# Need to change jquery from random image to sequence

Tags: jquery

so it's pre loading images

```
  var headerImages = [
       'images/logoa.png',
       'images/logob.png',
       'images/logoc.png',
       'images/logod.png',
       'images/logoe.png',
       'images/logog.png',
       'images/logoh.png',
       /* 'images/logoi.png', */
       'images/test/logoa.png',
       'images/test/logob.png'];
```

and then picking a random one on each page scroll, how do I make it  in sequence, meaning from top to bottom of the pre load?

```
....

jQuery.preLoadImages(headerImages);


jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  jQuery('#sidebar').css('backgroundImage', 'url(' +
headerImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*headerImages.length)] + ')');
});
```

So I guess it's this part `Math.floor(Math.random()*headerImages.length)` but I have no idea what to do..

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I forgot to include the pre load function, just wondering if it makes any difference (and thanks so much for your quick replies!)

Comment: (function(jQuery) {
  var cache = [];
  // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
  jQuery.preLoadImages = function() {
    if(typeof arguments[0] == 'object') {
      var new_args = [];
      for (var i = arguments[0].length; i--;) {
        new_args.push(arguments[0][i]);
      }
      arguments = new_args;
    }
    var args_len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
      cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
  }
})(jQuery)

Comment: No the preloader function will no make a difference here, if all you want to do is remove the random order of the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by storing the current image index in an variable and the adding at each scroll. Then setting it to zero when it reaches the end of the list:

```
jQuery.preLoadImages(headerImages);

    var index = 0; // set the variable

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    jQuery('#sidebar').css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + headerImages[index] + ')');

    index ++; // add one to point to the next image on the next scroll

    if(index==headerImages.length) index = 0; // If the counter is at the end of the array then set it to zero again

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x =0;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  jQuery('#sidebar').css('backgroundImage', 'url(' +
headerImages[x] + ')');
x++
if (x == headerImages.length)
{
 x =0;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`headerImages` seems to be an array so you should be fine if you do a loop from 0 to headerImages.lenght and do something like:

```
jQuery('#sidebar').css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + headerImages[x] + ')');
```

Inside the loop, where `x` is the variable you increment from 0 to max.